# Unifying similar functions in one

Tags: python

I have some calculations on biological data. Each function calculates the total, average, min, max values for one list of objects.
The idea is that I have a lot of different lists each one is for a different object type.
I don't want to repeat my code for every function just changing the "for" line and the call of the object's method!

For example:

Volume function:

```
def calculate_volume(self):
    total = 0
    min = sys.maxint
    max = -1
    compartments_counter = 0

    for n in self.nodes:

        compartments_counter += 1
        current = n.get_compartment_volume()
        if min > current:
            min = current
        if max < current:
            max = current

        total += current

    avg = float(total) / compartments_counter
    return total, avg, min, max
```

Contraction function:

```
def get_contraction(self):
    total = 0
    min = sys.maxint
    max = -1
    branches_count = self.branches.__len__()

    for branch in self.branches:

        current = branch.get_contraction()
        if min > current:
            min = current
        if max < current:
            max = current

        total += current

    avg = float(total) / branches_count

    return total, avg, min, max
```

Both functions look almost the same, just a little modification!

I know I can use the sum, min, max, ... etc. but when I apply them for my values they take more time than doing them in the loop because they can't be called at once.

I just want to know if is it the right way to write a function for every calculation? (i.e. a professional way?) Or maybe I can write one function and pass the list, object type and the method to call.

Comment: I think I understand now what you mean by "can't be called at once" but I'd be extremely skeptical if you're saying that globbing the 4 calculations into a single python func is faster than 4 builtin C calls over the same data. Yes: it would iterate over the data 4 times BUT in a very optimized way each time. My benchmarks show the builtins win everytime (see my edited reply below).

Comment: This should probably on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say without seeing the rest of the code but from the limited view given I'd reckon you shouldn't have these functions in methods at all. I also really don't understand your reasoning for not using the builtins("they can't be called at once?"). If you're implying that implementing the 4 statistical methods in a single pass in python is faster than 4 passes in builtin (C) then I'm afraid you have a very wrong assumption.

That said, here's my take on the problem:

```
def get_stats(l):
    s = sum(l)
    return (
        s,
        float(s) / len(l),
        min(l),
        max(l))

# then create numeric lists from your data and send 'em through:

node_volumes = [n.get_compartment_volume() for n in self.nodes]
branches = [b.get_contraction() for b in self.branches]

# ...

total_1, avg_1, min_1, max_1 = get_stats(node_volumes)
total_2, avg_2, min_2, max_2 = get_stats(branches)
```

EDIT

Some benchmarks to prove that builtin is win:

MINE.py

```
import sys

def get_stats(l):
    s = sum(l)
    return (
        s,
        float(s) / len(l),
        min(l),
        max(l)
    )


branches = [i for i in xrange(10000000)]

print get_stats(branches)
```

Versus YOURS.py

```
import sys

branches = [i for i in xrange(10000000)]

total = 0
min = sys.maxint
max = -1
branches_count = branches.__len__()

for current in branches:
    if min > current:
        min = current
    if max < current:
        max = current

    total += current

avg = float(total) / branches_count

print total, avg, min, max
```

And finally with some timers:

```
smassey@hacklabs:/tmp $ time python mine.py 
(49999995000000, 4999999.5, 0, 9999999)

real    0m1.225s
user    0m0.996s
sys 0m0.228s
smassey@hacklabs:/tmp $ time python yours.py 
49999995000000 4999999.5 0 9999999

real    0m2.369s
user    0m2.180s
sys 0m0.180s
```

Cheers

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you very much. ^_^

Answer (score 1):

First, notice that while it is probably more *efficient* to call `len(self.branches)` (don't call `__len__` directly), it is more *general* to increment a counter in the loop like you do with `calculate_volume`. With that change, you can refactor as follows:

```
def _stats(self, iterable, get_current):
    total = 0.0
    min_value = None  # Slightly better
    max_value = -1
    counter = 0
    for n in iterable:
        counter += 1
        current = get_current(n)
        if min_value is None or min_value > current:
            min_value = current
        if max_value < current:
            max_value = current
        total += current
    avg = total / denom
    return total, avg, min_value, max_value
```

Now, each of the two can be implemented in terms of `_stats`:

```
import operator

def calculate_volume(self):
    return self._stats(self.nodes, operator.methodcaller('get_compartment_volume'))

def get_contraction(self):
    return self.refactor(self.branches, operator.methodcaller('get_contraction'))
```

`methodcaller` provides a function `f` such that `f('method_name')(x)` is equivalent to `x.method_name()`, which allows you to factor out the method call.

Comment: How is using `methodcaller` different than `getattr`?

Comment: @DeepSpace I was asking myself the same thing, had never seen that one before. To answer your question though: it's not. See here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller

Comment: `methodcaller` is basically a convenience to avoid having to write, e.g., `lambda obj: getattr(obj, 'get_contraction')()`. (It's also a bit more efficient, since it is implemented in C rather than as a user-defined function.)

Comment: I think this will break on Python3, as it doesn't allow to compare `None` to anything else.

Comment: @DeepSpace Oh, I forgot to update the OP's code to use `None` as a sentinel instead of `maxint`. I'll fix.

Comment: (Also, I tend to look for excuses to use things like `methodcaller`. I think the main benefit of passing a function as an argument rather than the name of a method is that it makes the code easier to test.)

Comment: Yea your answer fits my question perfectly, but the chosen one is faster in execution.
Thank you very much I learnt new technique :D

Answer (score 1):

> Or maybe I can write one function and pass the list, object type and the method to call.

Altough you can definitely pass a function to function, and it's actually a very common way to avoid repeating yourself, in this case you can't because each object in the list has it's own method. So instead, I'm passing the function's name as a string, then using `getattr` in order to get the actual callable method from the object. Also note that I'm using `len()` instead of explicitly calling `__len()__`.

```
def handle_list(items_list, func_to_call):
    total = 0
    min = sys.maxint
    max = -1
    count = len(items_list)

    for item in items_list:

        current = getattr(item, func_to_call)()
        if min > current:
            min = current
        if max < current:
            max = current

        total += current

    avg = float(total) / count

    return total, avg, min, max
```

Comment: Yea your answer fits my question perfectly, but the chosen one is faster in execution.
Thank you very much I learnt new technique :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getattr( instance, methodname)` to write a function to process lists of arbitrary objects.

```
def averager( things, methodname):
    count,total,min,max = 0,0,sys.maxint,-1
    for thing in things:
         current = getattr(thing, methodname)()  

         count += 1
         if min > current:
             min = current
         if max < current:
             max = current
         total += current

    avg = float(total) / branches_count
    return total, avg, min, max
```

Then inside your class definitions you just need

```
    def calculate_volume(self): return averager( self.nodes, 'get_compartment_volume')

    def get_contraction(self): return averager( self.branches, 'get_contraction' )
```

Comment: Yea your answer fits my question perfectly, but the chosen one was faster in execution.
Thank you very much I learnt new technique :D

Answer (score 1):

Writing a function that takes another function that knows how to extract values from the list is very common. In fact, `min` and `max` both take arguments to such and effect.

eg.

```
items = [1, 0, -2]
print(max(items, key=abs)) # prints -2
```

So it's perfectly acceptable to write your own function that does the same. Normally, I would just create a new list of all the values you want to examine and then work with that (eg. `[branch.get_contraction() for branch in branches]`). But perhaps space is an issue for you, so here is an example using a generator.

```
def sum_avg_min_max(iterable, key=None):
    if key is not None:
        iter_ = (key(item) for item in iterable)
    else:
        # if there is no key, just use the iterable itself
        iter_ = iter(iterable)

    try:
        # We don't know sensible starting values for total, min or max. So use 
        # the first value.
        total = min_ = max_ = next(iter_)
    except StopIteration:
        # can't have a min or max if we have no items in the iterable...
        raise ValueError("empty iterable") from None
    count = 1

    for item in iter_:
        total += item
        min_ = min(min_, item)
        max_ = max(max_, item)
        count += 1

    return total, float(total) / count, min_, max_
```

Then you might use it like this:

```
class MyClass(int):
    def square(self):
        return self ** 2

items = [MyClass(i) for i in range(10)]
print(sum_avg_min_max(items, key=MyClass.square)) # prints (285, 28.5, 0, 81)
```

This works because when you fetch an instance method from the class it gives your underlying function itself (without `self` bound). So we can use it as the key. eg.

```
str.upper("hello world") == "hello world".upper()
```

With a more concrete example (assuming items in `branches` are instances of `Branch`):

```
def get_contraction(self):
    result = sum_avg_min_max(self.branches, key=Branch.get_contraction)
    return result
```

Comment: Thank you very much your answer was very helpful and I learnt new things :D